# Qt 5.1.1 + LibCurl Compile error: 'CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, qt, libcurl

I am trying to compile the libcurl smtp client example code inside of a cli program in Qt Creator.

Link to code - http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/smtp-tls.html

I downloaded libcurl-7.19.3-win32-ssl-msvc.zip from their site, and added

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\Users\test\Desktop\curl\include
```

To my .pro file.

However, when I try to compile, I get

```
error: 'CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM' was not declared in this scope
in definition of macro 'curl_easy_setopt'


error: 'CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT' was not declared in this scope
in definition of macro 'curl_easy_setopt'
```

I did some googling and couldn't find much, so hoping someone here could lend a hand. All of the other functions/names seem to be picked up fine except those two, maybe I am not linking something properly? Thanks.

Solved - This was an error on libcurl's side in the latest version of libcurl, this error is not present on curl-7.27.0

Comment: Your question aside, why are you using libcurl with Qt? Qt has a robust networking and web request API.

Comment: For smtp client functionality.

Comment: Since I've gotten no response would you care to share some of these robust networking functions you speak of? All I was able to find was some half of a git project that doesn't even compile.

Comment: I don't know about SMTP specifically, but I've used Qt's TCP/UDP sockets as well as its HTTP request tools. They are super simple. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtnetwork/qtnetwork-index.html

Comment: Also, see: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtnetwork/qnetworkaccessmanager.html

Comment: Not trying to create a SMTP client from scratch. Maybe that wouldn't be so bad without SSL/TLS, but thanks for input.